# Image map drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I have developed a website with Drupal 8 and I want to have hot spots on a specific image that opens a modal or lightbox. Are there any modals compatible with drupal 8 that can preform this task?

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe use the module [Image Annotator [Annotorious]](https://www.drupal.org/project/img_annotator) but it's maybe not exactly what you need

---

Unfortunately I'm not sure any other module will do the job for Drupal 8, now, to achieve your goal.

I suggest you create your own module for Drupal 8.

You could also take a look of [Responsive Image Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_imagemaps) which is a Drupal 7 module that uses the Javascript library [jQuery RWD Image Maps](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps).

It would be a great start for your own module.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Drupal 8 module below. it seems it is the only one ported to D8 at the moment

https://www.drupal.org/project/image_pointer

maybe not integrated with Drupal, but if you use CKEditor there's a plugin that might work: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/imagemaps

if you are using ckeditor with the wysiwyg module it should be fairly easy to configure a new plugin so that users can use it in a wysiwyg